# Android App Simple calendar/scheduler

Tags: java, beginner, android

Wanted to make a schedule for myself that was (hopefully) light-weight. Right now it just has the bare essential function of saving text for a certain day.

Looking for advice on literally anything that could improve the code ie. more efficient/better style/adhering to standards/etc.

Here is a link to the github repository for easier reading: [https://github.com/kalenpw/Kalendar](https://github.com/kalenpw/Kalendar/tree/c43d690152e4a2c7526e7146ff9bad09c68f4ad7)

And the three main classes:

### MainActivity.java

```
/*
    kalenpw
    kalenpwilliams@gmail.com

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    For a copy of the GNU General Public License see
    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/
 */

package com.example.kalenpw.kalendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    CalendarView _Calendar = null;
    Button _ButtonSave = null;
    EditText _EditText = null;

    Day  _SelectedDay = null;

    ArrayList<Day> _Schedule = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Load previous entries
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler();
        _Schedule = fh.deserializeObject();

        //Setup widgets for easier access
        _Calendar = (CalendarView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        _ButtonSave = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        _EditText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        //TODO update _SelectedDay so app doesn't crash if a choice is made before changing
        //the date

        //Set up button
        _ButtonSave.setText(R.string.btn_edit);
        updateEditText();

        _ButtonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        _Calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                selectedDateChanged(view, year, month, dayOfMonth);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Method called when the Save/Edit button is clicked
     * @param view
     */
    public void onClick(View view){
        String buttonText = _ButtonSave.getText().toString();

        if(buttonText.equals("Edit")){
            handleEdit();
        }
        else if(buttonText.equals("Save")){
            handleSave(view);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Handles editting of schedule
     */
    private void handleEdit(){
        _ButtonSave.setText(R.string.btn_save);
        updateEditText();
    }

    /**
     * Handles saving schedule
     * @param View view - current view
     */
    private void handleSave(View view){
        _ButtonSave.setText(R.string.btn_edit);
        updateEditText();
        closeOnScreenKeyboard(view);
        if(dayIsAlreadyInList(_SelectedDay)){
            int indexOfDay = getIndexOfSpecificDay(_SelectedDay);
            _SelectedDay.setMessage(_EditText.getText().toString());
            _Schedule.remove(indexOfDay);
            _Schedule.add(indexOfDay, _SelectedDay);
        }
        else{
            _SelectedDay.setMessage(_EditText.getText().toString());
            _Schedule.add(_SelectedDay);
        }

        //Save serialized object
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler();
        fh.serializeObject(_Schedule);
    }

    /**
     * Method called when CalendarView selected date changes
     * @param view - current view
     * @param year - year selected
     * @param month - month selected
     * @param dayOfMonth - day selected
     */
    private void selectedDateChanged(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
        //Switch back to view mode
        _ButtonSave.setText(R.string.btn_edit);
        _EditText.setText("");
        updateEditText();

        closeOnScreenKeyboard(view);

        Day selectedDay = new Day(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        _SelectedDay = selectedDay;
        if(dayIsAlreadyInList(selectedDay)){
            int indexOfFoundDay = getIndexOfSpecificDay(selectedDay);
            Day day = _Schedule.get(indexOfFoundDay);
            _EditText.setText(day.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of a specific day from the _Schedule ArrayList
     * Note: this method does no checking that the day exists so ensure
     * dayIsAlreadyInList() is called prior to calling this method
     * @param toFind - Day that needs found
     * @return int - index of given day
     */
    private int getIndexOfSpecificDay(Day toFind){
        for(Day day : _Schedule){
            if(daysAreEqual(toFind, day)){
                return _Schedule.indexOf(day);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the on screenkeyboard
     * @param view - current view
     */
    private void closeOnScreenKeyboard(View view){
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if two given days are equal ie same day, month, and year
     * @param dayOne - first Day to check
     * @param dayTwo - second Day to check
     * @return boolean - true if they are the same day, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean daysAreEqual(Day dayOne, Day dayTwo){
        boolean areEqual = true;
        if(dayOne.getDay() != dayTwo.getDay() ||
                dayOne.getMonth() != dayTwo.getMonth() ||
                dayOne.getYear() != dayTwo.getYear()){
            areEqual = false;
        }
        return areEqual;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a given day is already in the _Schedule list
     * @param dayToCheck - Day to check if it is alredy part of list
     * @return boolean - true if the Day is already in list, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean dayIsAlreadyInList(Day dayToCheck){
        boolean alreadyContains = false;
        for(Day day : _Schedule){
            if(daysAreEqual(day, dayToCheck)){
                alreadyContains = true;
                return alreadyContains;
            }
        }
        return alreadyContains;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the status of EditText widget so it can be interacted with properly
     */
    private void updateEditText(){
        String btnText = _ButtonSave.getText().toString();
        if(btnText.equals("Save")){
            _EditText.setEnabled(true);
            _EditText.setFocusable(true);
            _EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            _EditText.setCursorVisible(true);
        }
        else if(btnText.equals("Edit")){
            _EditText.setEnabled(true);
            _EditText.setFocusable(false);
            _EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            _EditText.setCursorVisible(false);
        }
    }

//
}
```

### Day.java

```
//Represents a day on calendar with associated message

package com.example.kalenpw.kalendar;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Day implements Serializable {
    //Fields
    private int _Year = -1;
    private int _Month = -1;
    private int _Day = -1;

    private String _Message;

    //Constructor
    public Day(int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay){
        _Year = newYear;
        _Month = newMonth;
        _Day = newDay;
    }

    //Getters & Setters
    public int getYear(){
        return _Year;
    }
    public int getMonth(){
        return _Month;
    }
    public int getDay(){
        return _Day;
    }
    public void setMessage(String newMessage){
        _Message = newMessage;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return _Message;
    }

}
```

### FileHandler.java

```
//Offloads various file actions to a sepaprate class

package com.example.kalenpw.kalendar;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Environment;

public class FileHandler {
    private String _completePath;

    //Constructor
    public FileHandler(){
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File(sdCard + "/kalendar");
        directory.mkdirs();
        File file =  new File(directory, "Schedule.ser");
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        _completePath = path;
    }

    /**
     * Deserializes an object
     * @return ArrayList<Day> the previously saved entries
     */
    public ArrayList<Day> deserializeObject(){
        ArrayList<Day> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(_completePath));
            list = (ArrayList<Day>) objectIn.readObject();
            objectIn.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Serializes an object
     * @param objToSerialize - object to be serialized
     */
    public void serializeObject(Object objToSerialize){
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(_completePath));
            outputStream.writeObject(objToSerialize);
            outputStream.close();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            outputStream.writeObject(objToSerialize);
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//
}
```

Comment: You may already know this but on Android 6.0 and up apps that use "dangerous permissions" need to ask for permission at runtime. As far as I know writing to the sd card needs WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE which is a dangerous permission https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: @Bethan I actually didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out however, I believe it does that automatically because when the app is launched for the first time it asks you to enable some permissions for that

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [Java naming convention.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) 
"Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed."

I also would reccomend not to do heavy operations in main thread, as for example, in your code in onCreate() method

```
    _Schedule = fh.deserializeObject();
```

It may cause [ANR - Application Not Responding](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)